# Multiple ID's in jquery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have this segment of code

```
$('#test').click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $('#hidethis').show();
});
$('#test2').click(function(){
  $('#hidethis').hide();
  $('#test').show();
})
```

This Code works fine, I'm however wanting to apply it to more elements. So i want to ideally add more ID's

I have tried this method which hasn't worked.

```
$('#test,#test3').each.click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $('#hidethis').show();
});
$('#test2,#test4').each.click(function(){
  $('#hidethis').hide();
  $('#test').show();
})
```

Will add a Fiddle if needed

Comment: use class instead of id

Comment: you don't need each --- $('#test,#test3').click(function(){}); should do

Comment: [.each](http://api.jquery.com/each/) is a function that you supply a callback to, it doesn't have a `.click`. You should be getting an error on the console.

Comment: Make a fiddle please, it is needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you need to do is the following:

```
$('#test, #test3').click(function(){
 $(this).hide();
 $('#hidethis').show();
});

$('#test2, #test4').click(function(){
  $('#hidethis').hide();
  $('#test').show();
});
```

[**JSFIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/corhtuzg/)

Comment: Wasn't working for me last night, Is now! How weird, must have had something wrong

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('.test').click(function () {
    $('.test').each(function(){
        $(this).hide();
    });
    $('#hidethis').show();
});

$('#hidethis').click(function () {
    $(this).hide();
    $('.test').show();
})
```

```css
.test {
    display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="hidethis">HIDE THIS</div>
<div class="test">SHOW ME</div>
<div class="test">SHOW ME1</div>
<div class="test">SHOW ME2</div>
<div class="test">SHOW ME3</div>
```